# After ajax call $_POST['name'] is still undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Html Code

```
<div class="container">
    <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
    <form method="POST" id="reg-form" action="register">
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input class="register-form-input" type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <label>Username:</label>
        <input  class="register-form-input" type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
            <label>Email:</label>
        <input  class="register-form-input" type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
        <label>ID Number:</label>
        <input  class="register-form-input" type="text" name="idnumber" id="idnumber"><br>
            <label>Password:</label>
        <input  class="register-form-input" type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
            <label for="name">Repeat Password:</label>
        <input  class="register-form-input" type="password" name="password1" id="password1"><br><br>
        <input type="submit"  name="submit"  id="register-submit" onclick="ajax_post();">
    </form>
    <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
</div>
```

Javascript File

```
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "register/index";
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var vars = "name="+name+"&username="+username;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        console.log(return_data);
      }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
}
document.querySelector('#reg-form').onsubmit=function(){
        return false;
}
```

Register Controller

```
<?php 
class Register extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo $_POST['name'];
    }
    public function index(){
        echo $_POST['name'];
        $this->view->render('register/index',false);
        $this->model->run();
        echo $_POST['name'];
    }
    public function run(){

    }
}
```

Issue is that When i return Data (ajax Response) in console it shows whole content and everywhere i have written echo $_POST['name'] appears only in console response,on page it's undefined. if you need to explain i'll make it more detailed. just $_POST['name'] is undefined on page,but not in console.

Comment: simple, it's because of your `<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>` that is throwing that error at you.

Comment: in your first code, `$_POST['name']` will never have a value since it comes from an ajax request ; surely it won't be defined in the calling script/page ; upon receiving the ajax request, you have to update the page with javascript

Comment: uhmm, could you be more specific?

Comment: i know that is because of $_POST['name'] but i can't figure out why Ajax doesn't send data to Register controller, url="register/index" and in index method is written $_POST['name'] but it's undefined as well,it's like doesn't get any data,but in reality it gets

Comment: http://pixs.ru/showimage/testpng_8254408_29486553.png here is an img, i have underlined Main part (asdasd) there is $_POST['name']

Comment: this post should not have been reopened, the story is clear here. I also rolled the question back; it is a duplicate.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner — It is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef). The question says that the value does not show up as undefined in the console log. It is asking why the page hasn't updated after the Ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

Ajax is not time travel.

This is what happens:

1. You make a request for a page to display in the browser window
2. The value is undefined and shows as such in the page
3. You use JavaScript to make a second, similar request to be handled with JS
4. The value is defined and shows correctly when you log the response

Making a second request does not change history. The results of the first request are unchanged and are still shown in the page.

If you want to load a whole new page, then don't use Ajax.

If you want to modify the page the user is already looking at based on the responce you get to your Ajax request, then you must write JavaScript (in your `onreadystatechange` function) to manipulate the DOM of the page.

Comment: man i just want to send data to Register_Model.php simple MVC structure, but data transfers to php after refresh only.

Comment: @DummyTarget — It transfers to PHP when you send the Ajax response. That just isn't reflected in the page because that page was sent before you made the Ajax response … and you've done nothing to update it.

Comment: and how to update? i mean somehow i got it because if i do document.querySelector('body').innerHTML=respons_data it updates and PHP gets value,but how to pass it without updating page? + it gets some bugs

Comment: @DummyTarget — If you want to change what the user sees then you have to update the page! You should probably design your API so it is less of a sledge hammer and just returns pure data (e.g. as JSON) and then update the specific bits you care about.

Comment: i have to do same if i don't care for UI and just want to send this javascript data to Php register ?

Comment: As mentioned repeatedly: The PHP is getting the value you send. You said yourself that you could see it being correctly echoed in console.log.

Comment: Yes it gets,but for some reasons doesn't go to database,goes only if refreshes. without refresh data is passed to php but can't go to database

Comment: Why would it go into the database? The only thing you do with anything in `$_POST` is echo it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165787/discussion-between-dummytarget-and-quentin).